# TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object Object] which has only a getter while converting xls-to-json

Tags: json, node.js, npm, protractor, converters

Below is the code i am using ,  Node version 4.2.5 ,xls-to-json@0.3.2 xls-to-json

```
  function convXLStoJSON1(inputfile,outputfile, sheetName)
     {

        node_xj = require("C:/Protractor_Scripts/node_modules/xls-to-json");

        node_xj({
                        input: inputfile,  // input xls 
                        output: outputfile, // output json 
                        //sheet:sheetName,
                        },

     function(err, result) {
                        if(err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        } else {
                        //console.log(result);
                        }
        });
        browser.sleep(500);
    };
```

Below is the complete error

> Selenium standalone server started at htt:56/w/hu
>
> [launcher] Error: TypeError: Cannot set property length of [object
>   Object] whichhas only a getter at sbcs_d
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\dist\cpexcel.js:904:20)
>
> at Object.decode
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\dist\cpexel.js:187:40)
>   at _gc2
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:19:23)
>   at Buffer.ReadShift [as read_shift]
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:18:13)
>   at parse_XLUnicodeStringNoCch
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:179:36)
>   at parse_XLUnicodeString
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:178:9)
>   at Object.parse_WriteAccess [as f]
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:059:17)
>   at slurp
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:5411:11)
>   at parse_workbook
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:559:15)
>   at parse_xlscfb
>   (C:\Protractor_Scripts\node_modules\xls-to-json\node_modules\xlsjs\xls.js:594:27)
>
> [launcher] Process exited with error code 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was with the Package.json in xls folder of xls-to-json package. I tried updating it with other Package.json files but did not work.

I installed xlsx-to-json instead xls-to-json , it worked fine.